# Rego regex to match a specific word from a sentence

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, boolean-logic, open-policy-agent, rego

I've written a regex

```
 \blates(t|)?\b
```

to search for a word "latest" in a sentence "/man/service/man-aaaaaa-lllll-latest/zzzn2-iii-ooo-x00_00-gg".

I'm testing a rule in 'Rego' through Rego playground, whenever there's a word 'latest' in a sentence, I want to get a boolean output as 'true'.

Rego Playground link: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/e3vDQyYKlc

Rego input

```
{
    "message": "/man/service/man-aaaaaa-lllll-latest/zzzn2-iii-ooo-x00_00-gg"
}
```

Rego rule:

```
package play

default hello = false

hello {
    m := input.message
    regex.match("\blates(t|)?\b", m)
}
```

Current output:

```
{
    "hello": false
}
```

Expected output whenever Regex has a match for the word 'latest':

```
{
    "hello": true
}
```

Please suggest if I've to use any other Regex condition to achieve the expected result
https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#regex

Comment: Maybe this is a usual issue with a backslash? Try `"\\blatest?\\b"`

Comment: I tried ```"\\blatest?\\b"```, but it's not matching for the word "latest" in the sentence "/man/service/man-aaaaaa-lllll-latest/zzzn2-iii-ooo-x00_00-gg"

Comment: Try 1) `regex.match(".*\blatest?\b.*", m)` or 2) `regex.match(".*\\blatest?\\b.*", m)`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, the second one has provided me with the expected result.  Rego playground link for your reference: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/ej12txWc9x

Comment: Hm, then I think even `regex.match("\\blatest?\\b", m)` will work. I get `"hello": true` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
regex.match("\\blatest?\\b", m)
```

or

```
regex.match(".*\\blatest?\\b.*", m)
```

See the [Rego playground demo](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/ej12txWc9x).

Note that `(t|)?` is a capturing group that matches a `t` or empty string, and is basically equal to `t?` pattern (there is no need to capture the `t`) that matches an optional `t` char.